# Recovering a file after having formatted from NTFS to EXT4

Tags: data-recovery, ntfs, ext4, format, bitcoin

I used to have windows 7 but I've recently formatted my hard drive to install kubuntu and I've just realized that I forgot to backup a hidden .dat file which defines my bitcoin wallet. Is it possible to recover this file? How can I do this? I need help.

Comment: Which wallet format were you using? https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet

Answer (score 0):

Scalpel is one of the best command line tool to recover deleted files in Ubuntu Linux. It can recover almost all types of files. It visits data blocks of files sequentially and identifies deleted files and recovers them instantly. You can install it by running following command in your terminal.

```
apt-get install scalpel
```

or

There are ways to do it, you can follow some of the guides here:

[recovery tools](http://e2undel.sourceforge.net/recovery-howto.html)

They show you some of the tools to use heuristics and guessing to put data back together.