# Data recovery from erased external HDD NTFS partion

Tags: 12.04, ntfs, data-recovery, external-hdd

I have erased my 1TB NTFS external HDD using **Startup disk Creator** accidentally. Is there any possibility I can get back my data.

Comment: maybe this will help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/350823/recovering-a-file-after-having-formatted-from-ntfs-to-ext4

Comment: NTFS being primarily a Windows format, there are a great many Windows-based utilities for recovering files from an NTFS partition.  Are these an option for you or do you need to do it from Linux?  I acknowledge that Windows based utilities are outside the scope of this site but wanted to point out that as an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the most powerful recovery software for most tasks is [Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) which is free and open source and can be found in Ubuntu's software catalog, but can also be run from Windows or Mac as well.

Its interface is relatively complex but its recovery is top-notch - in case of accidental formatting or destroying of a partition you probably want to use one of its advanced modes where it can recognise a destroyed partition:

[This is the exact procedure to follow for doing this for an NTFS partition](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/Undelete_files_from_NTFS_with_TestDisk).

Teskdisk's "simple" mode will use a more naive recovery type that doesn't necessarily take the partition format into account and therefore doesn't necessarily recover fragmented files or certain file types, or get the folder structure.  So you want to follow this NTFS based advanced recovery if it works for you as it will be much better.

If too much of the NTFS structure such as the master file table are corrupted or missing, then you may not be able to recover with this method and you may need to use the more naive methods in Testdisk (or as recommended in their documentation, use photorec, also open source).  Hopefully you don't need to resort to this as it can be very patchy to recover based on file signatures.

Comment: Actually, I read from the post that it is not an NTFS disk any more, as it is turnde into a bootable Ubuntu disk.

Comment: @Jacob yes, hence the need to use disk recovery software to try and restore files from the old NTFS partition.  The OP is not interested in what its new format is, it was a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I used "power data recovery". It could get back approximately all the data.. a few images were damaged.